# New IIS 10 binding not working

Tags: iis, iis-10

I had my live site working with the name:

```
mysite.domain.com
```

and I created a brand new server hosting my test site:

```
mysite-test.domain.com
```

My new site is finally ready so I changed the DNS entry of mysite.domain.com to point at the new test site.

I added a second binding in the new IIS

```
https 192.168.10.10 mysite-test.domain.com
https 192.168.10.10 mysite.domain.com
```

Unfortunately this bind doesn't work - the page just loads for ages and gives me a 'site not found' error. I tired nslookup and it is resolving to the correct IP. The SSL cert is valid for both hostnames.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: "the page just loads for ages", so which URL is in address bar? "I tried nslookup", so which domain name? If you can clearly describe the issue, then you are not too far from the answer.

Comment: The issue has now been resolved, but the address was https://mysite.domain.com and nslookup mysite.domain.com. Seems that wasn't the issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite nslookup returning the correct IP, rebooting my pc worked.